# Error with Nested Serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following model and serializer:

```
class SeminarTracking(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_tax_seminar = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    cid = models.ForeignKey('clients.Client')
    invite = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    invite_2 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    rsvp = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    attendees = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    names = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tax_seminars_tracking'

class SeminarTrackingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SeminarTracking
```

Client serialize:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #adwebsite = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    #adissue = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)
    #category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
    status = serializers.Field()
    seminars = SeminarTrackingSerializer(source='seminartracking_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Client
```

Whenever I access the client via the API, I get the following error:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'tax_seminars_tracking.cid_id' in 'field list'")
```

If I access `seminartracking_set` in a view or template, it works no problems. Is there something I am missing? - Note the primary key of the client model is `clientid`, not `id` - not sure if that's relevant.

Many thanks, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify the column name on the "cid" feild.